# How to tackle fatal error?

Tags: php

Hi all i want to take some part of string by using substr function of php.

Here is my code

```
$error = array("Warning","Parse error","*Fatal error");
$errorfunction = ''; 
      foreach( $error as $error => $err){     
      if(preg_match("/$err/", $script_output, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
        $errorfunction .= "<b>$err<br>";
      }
      if($errorfunction != ''){ 
      $script_output =substr($script_output,0,strpos($script_output,"in ")); 
      }
```

Whole function is running successfully, But When i am getting fatal error function is not working.

You guys can see that i have defined array of error

```
$error = array("Warning","Parse error","*Fatal error");
```

and i have defined fatal error as *fatal error because in php whenever fatal error is arise it is started as *fatal error

But this is not working. Please guys suggest me where i am wrong.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The `*` at the beginning of your string has a special meaning in regular expressions; using it there is a syntax error for PCRE. *Turn on errors so you know what’s going wrong*, then don’t use regular expressions to find static strings:

```
if (strpos($script_output, $err) !== false) {
    $errorfunction .= "<b>$err<br>";
}
```

If your real use case is more complicated, [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) will escape characters with special meaning in regular expressions for you. (Make sure to pass a delimiter.)

Comment: I had already turn on error by error_reporting(E_ALL); but by this not error reproduced

Comment: You have said me to use preg_quote. I am using but still the problem is same, i want to take substring from this <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function sanjay() in <b>/home/code1/public_html/eval/exec.php(24) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>2</b><br /> and substring from starting to word "in "

Comment: @user2372214: Well, then there’s the problem that there is no `*` in that. So take it out.